# Create a gallery from a CCK ImageField

Tags: drupal, gallery, cck, image-gallery

**What I have**

Currently I have a view that creates a list of entries, each entry has a title, description and multipule images. The view just shows the list right now and all the photos are group from the images field show when you preview the view. (the view is a block)

**What I am trying to build**

The list works, however instead of just showing all the photos, (3 - 6images) I would like to show only one image, then when you click the image a light box pops up and you can browse all the images.

*I have lightbox and imagecache installed.*

I am guessing there is a module or guide already out that but i don't know that correct terms to find the information. A link or some module recommendation would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Show all images of row, but hide via styling other images except first/last - theming views or styling css
2. if lightbox, these images should have one group with rel=lightbox['CurrentRow#XXX'] in current row - easy via theming views
3. Click on first image, it's should browse all images of current row grouped by one "rel"...

Comment: Thanks that's actually a really simple solution, I like it.